# What kind of compression/encoding is this program using?

Tags: decompress

The program I am looking at creates 3 different tables.

The first two tables are created at the same time, one entry at a time. Table 1 is 256 1 byte entries. Table 2 is 256 2 byte entries. All the values in table 2 go from low to high.

After table 1 and 2 are completed, table 3 is created. Table 3 is consecutive and increasing 1 byte values from 0x00 to 0xFF. For example there might be 12 repeating values of 0x00, then 8 repeating values of 0x01, and then 5 values of 0x02, all the way up to 0xFF. Table 3 is a variable length depending on the data.

If the decompressed data value was 0x00c5, the program will first pull 0x00 from table 3, followed by 0xc5.

Update: The right byte in table 2 is the counter for each hex value in table 3. For example if the first value in table 2 is 0x01FF, then there will be 256 values of 0x00 in table 3.

Comment: Can you share the program you are trying to reverse? or some simple sample input/outputs?

Comment: It appears that this is range encoding. The first table is the probabilities of 00-FF and table 2 is the ranges for the encoding.